# Gas oven with glow bar ignition - how should it work?

Tags: oven, stove

I have a Maytag Magic Chef 34JN-2CKX-ON gas stove. The oven stopped heating. There is a bottom burner and a top burner bar. When I turn the oven knob to temperature the bottom glow bar comes on and gets very hot. The top one does not come on. As I understand there are temp. sensors at the igniters that switch the gas on if hot enough. Should the bottom burners come on, or do both igniters need to come to temperature before any gas gets turned on?
What would be the first troubleshooting steps? Check fuses and replace top glow bar?

Comment: Typically the upper burner only turns on for broiling. Have you tried that setting?

Comment: No, I have not. I will do so tonight.

Comment: Is gas flowing at all?

Comment: The stove top burners work. And when put the oven on the 'warm' setting, nothing happened but I could smell gas. I didn't smell anything on the regular 'bake' setting.

Comment: Yes, on broil the top burner comes on fairly immediately.

Comment: Yesss! Thanks isherwood for the broiler explanation. I never paid attention to that, but then again I don't do the cooking. So, I switched the glow bars and now it's reversed: oven works, broiler not. Now just need to find a the part.